# How do you display errors by editing the php.ini file in HHVM?

Tags: hhvm

I am using CentOS 7 and I have tried to edit the php.ini file located /etc/hhvm/php.ini.

I added the line

`display_errors=On`

The only two other lines in php.ini are

```
date.timezone="America/New_York"
hhvm.dynamic_extension_path = /usr/local/lib64/hhvm/extensions
```

When I try to run a page it shows a blank page (because of fatal error). But when I run the same file from the command line with

`$ hhvm filename.php`

Then the fatal error is displayed. How can I make errors show up while I develop? In regular PHP I can edit this in php.ini, or even just add lines like these

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I have no idea how to do this in HHVM.

Comment: Why couldn't you just add those lines to `php.ini`: `display_startup_errors= 1`, `display_errors = 1` and `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`?

Comment: I did try to add all those in php.ini, just now. But the things I add in php.ini about error has no effect. It just shows a blank page as if I had turned of all errors.

Comment: Does it need to be restarted to reinitialize your updated config?

Comment: I already restarted it. in $ vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/hhvm.service, I start the hhvm service with this command, ExecStart=/usr/bin/hhvm -c /etc/hhvm/server.ini -c /etc/hhvm/php.ini --user hhvm --mode daemon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `display_errors` may or may not work in HHVM. There have been [some issues](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/3780) with it, and I'm not sure what the current status is. You should check your log file.
- Make sure you use a numeric value for `error_reporting` if you set it in the INI file. (Setting it with a constant in *code* is fine.) [This bug](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4720) prevents constants from working in INI files.